# Bootstrap datatable column width

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I am new to Bootstrap and currently modifying a website.

My goal is to add the new column, it is done. But it pushed the last column to wrapped.

The picture below explains my expectation
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you please try `white-space: nowrap;`  in your heading.  Hope this help

Comment: Or use `display:flex` on container, See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Answer (score 0):

**To specify the column widths,**
*Used the code below:*

```
$('#table_id').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { "width": "20%", "targets": 0 }
  ]
} );
```

> where `#table_id` should be replaced with your table ID

**To keep *View Docket*, *Wizard* and *Express* not wrapping,**
Use any inline element like *`span`* or *`i`* or you can use `display: inline;` with any element and `white-space: nowrap;` if required.